# one widget different behaviour - magento 2

Tags: magento2, cms, home, widget, magento2.0.8

**Widget-Block:** app/code/Gworks/Recentviewed/Block/Widget/Recent.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Gworks\Recentviewed\Block\Widget;

/**
 * Reports Recently Viewed Products Widget
 */
class Recent extends \Magento\Reports\Block\Product\Viewed implements \Magento\Widget\Block\BlockInterface
{
    /**
     * Internal constructor
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
    parent::_construct();
    $this->addColumnCountLayoutDepend('1column', 5)
        ->addColumnCountLayoutDepend('2columns-left', 4)
        ->addColumnCountLayoutDepend('2columns-right', 4)
        ->addColumnCountLayoutDepend('3columns', 3);
    }

}
```

**Widget-Tempalte:** app/code/Gworks/Recentviewed/view/frontend/templates/widget/recently_widget.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * @var $block \Magento\Reports\Block\Product\Viewed
 */
?>
<?php
if ($exist = ($block->getRecentlyViewedProducts() && $block->getRecentlyViewedProducts()->getSize())) {
    $type = 'widget-viewed';
    $mode = 'grid';

    $type = $type . '-' . $mode;

    $image = 'recently_viewed_products_grid_content_widget';
    $title = __('Recently Viewed');
    $items = $block->getRecentlyViewedProducts();

    $showWishlist = true;
    $showCompare = true;
    $showCart = true;
    $rating = 'short';
    $description = ($mode == 'list') ? true : false;
}
?>

<?php
if($exist)
{
    echo "success";
}
else
{
    echo "unsuccess";
}
?>
```

**Behaviour-1**

When I insert widget in cms static block

```
{{widget type="Gworks\Recentviewed\Block\Widget\Recent" template="widget/recently_widget.phtml" c_recent_count="3"}}
```

I got unsuccess message

**Behaviour -2**

When I add through **content->widget->add widget** set to CMS home page

I got success message.

> I am looking getting success in both of the way.

can anyone suggest me to why it is behave like this?